# Catch all query parameters, model data, routes to action methods to prevent XSS attacks

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, xss

I was thinking to catch all parameters, route info, other form data that is input by the user, so I can encode it to prevent XSS attacks on my website. I want to do this globally, and not for one particular controller. How to do this in WEB API 2.0 .net ?

Comment: microsoft has a good [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-2.1#encoding-url-parameters) on this topic.

Comment: yes, but it does not answer my question to catch all parameters, before it reaches the controller and action method

Comment: Note that you can't prevent xss this way. Encoding must be specific to the context where dynamic data will be written to - you shouldn't (and can't in general) have this info on the input side (see separation of concerns). Also what about DOM XSS? If this solution was viable and xss could be prevented so easily, why would the framework not just... do it?

Comment: And it's even worse than that, applying encoding on the input righ away *prevents* proper xss protection because of the double encoding problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a DelegatingHandler for your needs. 
Every request first go through the handler where you can intercept them:

```
public class RequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Validate the uri and or encode it
        Console.WriteLine(request.RequestUri);

        //Validate the content
        Console.WriteLine(request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        // If you like, create a whole new request or cancel it.
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

You  can register it globally:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {            
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new RequestHandler());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

As further reference, see the web api poster: https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf

Happy coding!

Comment: Potential future visitors: While this is a nice solution to the specific question, note that this is not a good idea for trying to prevent xss. See my comments on the question.